# Error:Cannot read packageName from E:\Lins\ZXing_luolu\ZxingScan-master\zxing-zxing-3.3.0\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android-studio, libraries, zxing

.png is my code short cut
[I'm failed to Import third-party source libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgGbk.png)
    //following are my build.gradle file
    //app module
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.meng.zxingscan"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile project(':zxing-zxing-3.3.0')
//    compile files('libs/core-3.3.0.jar')

}
```

//zxing module
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.meng.zxingscan"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:18.+'
}
```

Comment: Error:Cannot read packageName from E:\Lins\ZXing_luolu\ZxingScan-master\zxing-zxing-3.3.0\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Please post the ```build.gradle``` script for both zxing and app modules.

Comment: I have uploaded it.

Comment: I would like to use ZXing's source code as part of our own application and then compile and debug.